# lo_import : parameters contains special characters

Tags: postgresql, pdf, import

I have to use lo_import function to save a pdf file into my db,

the problem is that there are some special characters contained in file's name :

lo_import('c:\file_é_é.pdf');

i have a file named file_é_é.pdf under C:.

but lo_import is not able to find it.

Does anyone has any ideas ?

thanks

Comment: Check if c and C are the same. Special characters aren't a problem in Linux nor OSX, but I can't test it under Windows.

Comment: Huh. I wonder if we're handing the text encoding for the filename correctly. What encoding is the database in? Are you using psql, Pgadmin, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Can you `fopen` it yourself? I don't think DB encoding has anything to do with local file names.

The function call above is missing the `*conn` parameter. Could that be the problem?